# Is there a minimum height for a small sub-panel?

Tags: subpanel, hot-tub

A few years ago I installed a very small sub-panel for hot tub and one outlet.  The panel is mounted on a stem wall outdoors about 1.5' off the ground. It only has 2 breakers in it:  a 240volt for the hot tub and a 120v for an outlet for a outdoor lighting transformer. Both are GFCI protected. The hot tub is due for replacement so now would be a good time to update the sub-panel location if needed. I have some flexibility in the wiring and am thinking maybe I should mount it on a pressure treated post. There is a potential discrete location that would work near the hot tub location.  Everything would be in appropriate conduit of course.

The reason I did that is I thought I needed a "local disconnect", I'm not sure if that was accurate, but I think it still is.

So my question is: "Is there a minimum height for a sub-panel?"

Comment: The dual pole (240V) breaker in the subpanel for the hot tub is a local disconnect as long as it is close enough to the hot tub.

Answer (score 4):

There's no minimum height, but it can't be higher than 6'7" at the highest point of the "operating handle."

The code specifically states:

> 240.24(A) Accessibility. Circuit breakers and switches containing fuses shall be readily accessible and installed so that the center of
> the grip of the operating handle of the switch or circuit breaker,
> when in its highest position, is not more than 2.0 m (6 ft 7 in.)
> above the floor or working platform...

You also need adequate working area in front of and to the sides of the panel and be able to open the panel door to at least 90º.

Comment: Take the you can’t touch metal out and I will up vote. The panel only has to have 30” wide measured from one side or the other or centered or the width of the panel if larger than 30” , the door has to open to 90 degrees and the height of the working space 6-1/2’  no minimum for height . 3’ in front of  (0-150v all 3 conditions 3’ per table 110.26) that’s all the clearance requirements.